# JQuery filter system -> set the Url filter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a working product filter system in PHP, JavaScript and Ajax for getting the data from the MySQL Database. All works fine. But now there is a single problem.

When the product filter hits on as example a check-box the filter render a Ajax page and filters the data in a DIV tag. All works fine. But in the URL the filter data is not displaying. So when i click on a link and go forward to another URL and I hit back button in the browser the whole filter will be reset (normal off-course).

HOW can i set the Browser url working with a Java.

So what i need is to set the filter name at the end of the url in the browser url and make it a forward url so that the end user can click back and see the last filtered result.

Can anyone help me please?

Examples of the working Product List Filter system:

```
    function showValues() {

    $("#productCont").css("opacity",0.5);
    $("#loader_id").css("opacity",1);

    var genrearray = new Array();       
    $('input[name="genrecheck"]:checked').each(function(){          
        genrearray.push($(this).val());     
    });
    var genre_checklist = "&gcheck="+genrearray;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the filter to be saved in the browser history, via a URL parameter.
One JavaScript solution would be to use:
[history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: yes but i also want to set the filter at the end of the url line like: /link.html?genre=1831,1902&category=1840

And then push the history!

Comment: Also my webpages uses .htacess for the SEO urls, is there a way to set the filters at the end with the pushState?

-> /link.html?genre=1831,1902&category=1840

Comment: Sorry, I have been at work all week.
I am more than willing to help out.
Using:  history.pushState({ foo: "bar" }, "page 2", "link.html?genre=1831,1902&category=1840");
...will change the url client side to what you want
I am not sure I am understanding your request completely.